# How to sort mat-option alphabetically in typescript in Angular 7 Material Design?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material2

As per [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), there is **no** orderBy pipe available to sort. As per the documentation I have to implement the sort in the component by myself. As I am very new to Angular, I am unsure, how to go about it. Can somebody please help out? I am looking for the actual code, which will do the trick.

Code for `component.ts` - I want to sort the `indianStates` as per `viewValue`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'addressentry',
  templateUrl: './addressentry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addressentry.component.css']
})
export class AddressentryComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit() {}

  indianStates: IndianStates[] = [
    {value: 'westbengal', viewValue: 'West Bengal'},
    {value: 'sikkim', viewValue: 'Sikkim'},
    {value: 'assam', viewValue: 'Assam'}
  ];
}

export interface IndianStates {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col form-group">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label >State</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of indianStates" [value]="state.value">
          {{state.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort it in component and then give sorted array to template.

Demo example (assuming you want to sort it alphabetically): [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtkza5)